# converting date from string to datetime in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am having an issue in converting date from string to DateTime.
for Example I have input field coming from Source as coverage_end_dt as 01/31/2018  Using variable Port I am converting it as :

```
sub str(COVERAGE_END_DT,1,2) || sub str(COVERAGE_END_DT,4,2)||substr(COVERAGE_END_DT,7,4)
```

this is something like i am removing all the slashes in the date field and output port  with date time as :

```
IIF(NOT ISNULL(v_COVERAGE_END_DT),TO_DATE(v_COVERAGE_END_DT,'MMDDYYYY'),NULL)
```

but I am getting an error as:

> Transformation [exp_Format_C360_Data] had an error evaluating output
>   column [o_INFO_RECEIVED_DT].

Error message is

> [<> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date
>   ... t:TO_DATE(s:'01011900',s:'MM/DD/YYYY')].

Same issue with with another field , input filed end_tms as 11/15/2016 04:39:25

I am converting the variable port as :

```
substr(END_TMS,1,2) || substr(END_TMS,4,2)||substr(END_TMS,7,4)||substr(END_TMS,12,2)||substr(END_TMS,15,2)||substr(END_TMS,18,2)
```

output port as :

```
IIF(NOT ISNULL(END_TMS),TO_DATE( v_END_TMS, 'MMDDYYYYHH:MI:SS'),NULL)
```

and iam getting error as

> Transformation [exp_Format_C360_Data] had an error evaluating output
>   column [o_INITIAL_DECISION_TMS].

Error message is

> [<> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date ... t:TO_DATE(s:'11152016043818',s:'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')].

Comment: The error was in o_INFO_RECEIVED_DT and o_INITIAL_DECISION_TMS columns. Please check the expression for those fields in the mapping.

Comment: i was getting error for all the date fields and all of them have the same logic.. so just copied one and pasted

Comment: Please recheck the fields you are getting error for. The format string in the log is different from the one in your code.

Comment: INPUT:RECEIPT_DT,VARABLE:substr(RECEIPT_DT,1,2) || substr(RECEIPT_DT,4,2)||substr(RECEIPT_DT,7,4),OUTPUT:IIF(NOT ISNULL(RECEIPT_DT),TO_DATE(v_RECEIPT_DT,'MM/DD/YYYY'),NULL), ERROR:Transformation [exp_Format_C360_Data] had an error evaluating output column [o_RECEIPT_DT]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date
... t:TO_DATE(s:'11152016',s:'MM/DD/YYYY')].

Comment: SIMILLARY FOR ANOTHER FILED WHERE I WANT DATE AND TIME ALSO..INPUT :END_TMS,VERIABLE:substr(END_TMS,1,2) || substr(END_TMS,4,2)||substr(END_TMS,7,4)||substr(END_TMS,12,2)||substr(END_TMS,15,2)||substr(END_TMS,18,2),OUTPUT:IIF(NOT ISNULL(END_TMS),TO_DATE( v_END_TMS, 'MMDDYYYYHH:MI:SS'),NULL), ERROR: Transformation [exp_Format_C360_Data] had an error evaluating output column [o_END_TMS]. Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date
... t:TO_DATE(s:'11152016043925',s:'MMDDYYYYHH:MI:SS')]

Comment: For Receipt Date, I can see the format string is not correct in your code. It should be 'MMDDYYYY'

Comment: For END_TMS, remove the colons from the format string.

Comment: Even after making the changes its still throwing the same error , my target is Flat file with date 19 and in the before expression  I am using DateTime  for output. will that make difference?

Comment: For which column are you getting the error now? If your target is flat file, you can directly write the date strings to the file, why are you converting them to dates?

Comment: actually i have 2 targets one is FF and other is oracle table , the FF is loading fine but the table is bombing with the same error as above.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to get rid of all the slashes. Just put the correct format in TO_DATE function. Next, try posting some screenshot. The error messages and the code you're pasting is very confusing.